# Windows 7 Snap - Windows Message?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, win64

In my windows form application I want to capture the windows 7 snap message, does anyone know which message is generated when the window is about to be snapped.

I tried to listen in to the application and it looks like WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x24; is generated.

Can anyone confirm if thats really the windows message for snap?

Comment: I would use spy++ and check for sure

Comment: I used Spy++ and tried the snap, but it didn't generate that message.

Comment: So what message did it generate when the window was snapped?

Answer (score 1):

A WM_GETMINMAXINFO is called to determine the minimum size and max size the window, its called during SNAP so that it does not resize the window beyond its actual outlined size, so if you have an application that is 500 in height and that is a constant height, you dont want windows to resize it to fit the height of your screen.

It should then call the SetWindowPlacement function.